# Is it possible to get the type signature of an F# function at runtime?

Tags: types, f#, signature, quotations

Let's say I define an F# function as follows:

```
let flip p = (snd p, fst p)
```

If I hover over "flip", Visual Studio will tell me that the type signature of this function is:

```
'a * 'b -> 'b * 'a
```

Is there any way to get this signature string for an arbitrary function at runtime?

Calling `GetType()` on `flip` gives me the .NET type, which isn't helpful. Perhaps I could use quotations somehow? For example, `printfn "%A" <@flip@>` gives me:

```
Lambda (tupledArg,
        Let (arg00@, TupleGet (tupledArg, 0),
             Let (arg01@, TupleGet (tupledArg, 1),
                  Call (None, flip, [arg00@, arg01@]))))
```

That's closer to what I want, but obviously still not right. I'd like to get the same simple, clean type signature that's available in the IDE.